# How to convert array of words to make a sentence?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, concatenation

I feel uncomfortable asking, but how do I convert an array of words to make a sentence ?

I keep finding the other way round.

Something like:

```
var a = ['hello', 'world'];
```

and obtain :

```
hello world
```

Comment: it's not a bad question for a beginner, imo... it's hard to search Google for these things, if you do not know the right terminology. in the future, you can begin your search with "javascript array ..." and begin to guess words in place of "...". Google's auto complete makes it much easier to find what you need. I'm only saying this, because to make it as a developer, you really need to learn how to use this tool.

Comment: Thank you Everyone. Yes, I'm still learning how to use both jquery and stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't need jquery.  Javascript has a very simple way of doing this with the join function:

```
a.join(" ");
```

Comment: Where in the question does he mention jQuery?

Comment: The person asking the question had this tagged ONLY as "jquery".  I reorganized the tags removing jquery and adding 'javascript' and 'arrays'.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 7):

Just join the elements of the array into a string using a space as a separator:

```
var sentence = a.join(" ");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like?

```
arr.join(" ");
```